# Laravel:5.5 Showing 403 Forbidden and Block My Project Access

Tags: php, laravel

Its strange, i can't understand why this happening with my laravel project. Before one week it was working fine and before 2 or 3 days i just updated my server **php version** from **5.6** to **7.1**. (even update my laravel too)

When i was using 5.6 project was running fine but now suddenly its start showing

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /dashboard/dashboard on this server.
```

Not always but after done some operation like delete, create etc its start showing this. And another more strange thing when i delete my stored cookies of my browser (laravel stored session):

**Screenshot:**

[image]

When i remove this data my site start working. Now i am not getting this issue on laravel end or on my server php end.

Can anyone tell me what kind of problem is this?

Comment: Do you use  htaccess?

Comment: yes, that is default htaccess that comes with laravel framework

Comment: delete all session in server and try this htaccess : https://pastebin.com/MFMD5th5

Comment: ok, i just paste the htaccess code but showing same thing..

Comment: Now, suppose if i have to again up my site i need to delete cookie data from browser..and another thing its working on Microsoft Edge fine and chrome still showing 403

Comment: What is suppose, there is problem in my php session. !

Comment: Is it possible to give me the site address?

Comment: mybe useful :‌https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27796724/apache-laravel-403-forbidden-header-not-allowed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172399/discussion-between-alihossein-shahabi-and-rahul-sharma).